# syscall_table_32.S file not found

Tags: kernel, filesystem, programming, system

I want to add a systemcall to Linux, but in training data we need to change the file `linux/arch/i386/kernel/entry.S` or `arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S`.  I can not found the files.
I looked and could not find and  I have not a folder named i386.
please Help me. is Necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need the source code of the Linux kernel. You can download it at [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/) or you install the package `linux-source` from Ubuntu. In the latter case you'll find some patches from Ubuntu applied.

Usually the sources live under `/usr/src`. If you have unpacked the files there or installed the package, you'll find the tree you mentioned above. So the most recent kernel version has a file called [`entry_32.S`](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S) and [`entry_64.S`](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S) in the subdirectory `arch/x86/kernel`. The part after `arch` has the name `x86` and not `i386` as you mentioned. If you want to use `i386` you should choose a kernel version below 3.7, because `i386` was removed from 3.7 on.

Answer (score 0):

the entry_64.S file isn't the equivalent file that you need to modify... depending on what you want to do. If you're  in the business of adding a custom syscall to your kernel, modify the file **/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl** .

Comment: ** entry_64.S isn't equivalent to the syscall table, but it is to entry.S